# Unable to get the IF condition in AWS CLI commands in Jenkins to work

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cli

I am trying to run a series for commands for aws through a Jenkins job but whenever it comes to the if condition, it throws an error

Here are the list of commands

```
echo '****** Updating ASG ********'
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name test-asg --desired-capacity 2 --min-size 2 --max-size 6
sleep 200
echo '****** Initiating Instance Refresh ********'
aws autoscaling start-instance-refresh --auto-scaling-group-name test-asg --preferences '{"InstanceWarmup": 300, "MinHealthyPercentage": 100}'
while true;
do
    instance_refresh_status=$(aws autoscaling describe-instance-refreshes --auto-scaling-group-name test-asg --query "InstanceRefreshes[0].Status" --output text --region us-east-1)
    if (( "$instance_refresh_status" == "Successful" )); then
        break
    fi
    sleep 10
done

echo '****** Finished Instance Refresh ********'

echo '****** Updating ASG back to normal ********'
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name test-asg --desired-capacity 1 --min-size 1
```

The error I get is this in the Jenkins output

```
+ instance_refresh_status=InProgress
+ InProgress == Successful
/tmp/jenkins8251579523029552853.sh: 10: /tmp/jenkins8251579523029552853.sh: InProgress: not found
```

No matter what I try to wrap the if condition in, (), (()), [], [[]] I get the same error as above.

Can you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `if [ "$instance_refresh_status" = "Successful" ]; then` (note the single square brackets and single equal sign).

There are two problems in your version: first, `(( ))` is a bashism, and your script is not running under bash. In any POSIX-compliant shell, `( )` runs its contents (as normal shell commands) in a subshell. bash (and some other shells) treat `(( ))` differently, but in a basic POSIX shell like dash (which I suspect you're running under), it just runs its contents in two layers of subshell. So it's running `"InProgress" == "Successful"` in a double-sub-shell, which treats `InProgress` as a command and `==` and `Successful` as arguments to it, and gets a "not found" error looking for the command.

If you want to use bash features (or don't know which features are bashisms and which will work in other shells), you should start the script with a proper bash-specific shebang line, like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (and don't override it by running the script with the `sh` command).

The second problem is that in bash, `(( ))` does *integer arithmetic* evaluation. Given `(( "InProgress" == "Successful" ))`, it will try to evaluate `InProgress` and `Successful` as integers. The details aren't important here, but essentially they'll both evaluate as 0, so since `0 == 0` is true, the test will come out as true even though they're completely different strings.

To do string comparisons, use `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`, and since `[[ ]]` is another bashism (as is `==` inside them), I'd recommend using `[ = ]` at least until you're certain of which shell your script is running under.

Comment: thank you for the input. Am trying it now.. will update you how it went.

Comment: yaay! it worked. A question though, does not having spaces after within the square brackets also cause an error ?

Comment: @YYashwanth, https://shellcheck.net is your friend

Comment: @YYashwanth Spaces are required between each element of the `[ ]` expression, including between the brackets and the strings to be compared (unlike assignment statements, where spaces around the `=` are forbidden). And I second the recommendation of [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net/), as it can point out a lot of common scripting mistakes.

Comment: That was the problem. I tried the square brackets but I did not space the elements out as shown below. Thanks for helping out and yep, I have bookmarked the shellcheck.net.
 if ["$instance_refresh_status" = "Successful"]